# Help with this trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone help me? Why is

$$\frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x) + 1} = \frac{\sec^{2}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{2\tan\big(\frac{x}{2}\big) + 2}$$

Comment: What does "senx" represent?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: senx is a sinx .

Comment: Do you know the $\cos(2\theta)$ identities?

Comment: thank u!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle y = \frac{x}{2}$.  Then:

$$\frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x) + 1} = \frac{1}{\sin(2y) + \cos(2y) + 1}$$

Using the double-angle identities:

$$ = \frac{1}{2\sin(y)\cos(y) + 2\cos^{2}(y) - 1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2\sin(y)\cos(y) + 2\cos^{2}(y)}$$

$$ = \frac{\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(y)}}{2\cdot\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)} + 2} = \frac{\sec^{2}(y)}{2\tan(y) + 2} =\boxed{\frac{\sec^{2}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{2\tan\big(\frac{x}{2}\big) 
 + 2}}\ \ \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x + \cos x + 1 = 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}$$

$$= 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \left(\cos \frac{x}{2} + \sin \frac{x}{2}\right) = 2 \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} \left(1 + \tan \frac{x}{2}\right) $$

Hence $$\frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x + 1} = \frac{1}{2 \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} \left(1 + \tan \frac{x}{2}\right)} = \frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2 \tan \frac{x}{2} + 2}$$

Comment: Sorry, which step are you referring to?